Ultralytics YOLOv8 Pose Estimation not respecting vertices order when drawing edges / colors on custom dataset
I am following the official documentation to train on a custom dataset for Human Pose Estimation from ultralytics in Python. I have a small dataset of 1 image labeled by me, and the predictions work as expected, so the vertices recognition and class recognition work fine.
The problem is that the way the program is drawing the vertices, with the edges and colors, does not match my skeleton. The nose from the YOLO training is being drawn on my ankle. The prediction actually works properly, but it is extremely ugly because it's drawing edges that should not exist (like connecting the knee vertex with the shoulder vertex). And also, my Pose estimation subjects are very similar to humans, so I assume if I have the same skeleton, training will be faster.
Things I have already done and tried:

Follow closely the labelling from the official docs, this is 0 for nose, 1 for left ear, so on.
Try another labelling to see if documentation is outdated. This causes the order of the coordinates in the txt for train and val to change, so I assumed it would change the colors and edges of the output. It does nothing, which is very weird to me.
Read standard datasets yaml options like the one from super-gradients on coco and copy the "edge_links", "edge_colors" and "keypoint_colors" options. That way even if my ordering is different, it should parse these options and draw them properly. It also did nothing, which seems to me I'm misunderstanding something about how the yaml should be written. But I do not see what.
Important note, I'm not using any automatic dataset creation tool, I'm creating all these files manually. I cannot use Roboflow because of image copyright reasons, so I'm using a local annotator. I have checked a dataset created in Roboflow (the tiger example from ultralytics) to see differences and I do not see them, they do not even define these things, but the results only show the vertices and not any edges. Which is also weird to me.
I am using the current version of ultralytics, just did pip install a couple of days ago.

Code that I have, extracted by the documentation, is this. My yaml is "checa.yaml".
yaml_of_model="yolov8n-pose.yaml"
model_to_load = "best.pt"
# Load a model
model = YOLO(yaml_of_model)  # build a new model from YAML
model = YOLO(model_to_load)  # load a pretrained model (recommended for training)
model = YOLO(yaml_of_model).load(model_to_load)  # build from YAML and transfer weights
results = model.train(data="./checa.yaml", epochs=4, imgsz=1920)
results = model('./screenshot_1.jpg')

for result in results:
    result.show()

An extract of my yaml:
# Dataset root directory
path: ...

# Train and validation directories
train: ...
val: ...

# Number of keypoints and dimensions (2 for x,y or 3 for x,y,visible)
kpt_shape: [17, 3]
flip_indexes: [ 0, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 10, 9, 12, 11, 14, 13, 16, 15,]

edge_links:
  - [0, 1]
  - ...

edge_colors:
 - [214, 39, 40]  # Nose -> LeftEye
 - ...


keypoint_colors:
  - [148, 103, 189]
  - ...

# Classes dictionary
names:
  0: FirstClass
  1: ...

